# How to use Join using Laravel Eloquent and MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, laravel, mongodb-query, laravel-5

I have two collections users and clients. I want to use join between this two collections. Use `hasMany` relations. My eloquent query as follows

```
$user_list = User::with('clientMaster')
                    ->where('client_status', '=', 1)
                    ->get()
                    ->toArray()
```

User Model

```
public function clientMaster()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Client', '_id', 'client_name');
}
```

Now, when I print `$user_list` output as below. This output comes from users collection

```
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [_id] => 5788bbe97ffbe04a467634e1
            [name] => Abc Pqr
            [email] => abc.pqr@xyz.in
            [client_id] => 57876dcdc83aa906e81371f4
            [client_master] => Array
                (
                )
        )
)
```

Now I want use join between client and user for fetcing client name on behalf of `client._id = users.client_id`. I don't know how to use join in laravel eloquent. Please suggest me.

Comment: Mongo is not a relational database. It doesn't have joins. Your query also has no join. `with()` doesn't use joins.